# Exclude Code from Running in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html, mobile

Is anyone aware of some code that I can use to exclude certain things from showing in a mobile browser.

I specifically want to exclude certain images and flash files from showing on a website - but only when viewed on a mobile browser.

Something like this but on;t know what 'code' would be.

```
<code><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="32" height="32" /></code>
```

If anyone is able to help I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can look up the [META tag with something like this](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/detect_apple_iphone_user_web_site_server.html)

JavaScript:

```
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_iphone = ((agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1);
if (is_iphone) { conditional code goes here }
```

Use that to set a variable and then use something like this to check your variable and [show/hide some content:](http://www.cssnewbie.com/showhide-content-css-javascript/)

XHTML:

```
<p>...This is all visible content... 
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" 
onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See more.</a>
</p>
<div id="example" class="more">
<p>...This content is hidden by default...</p>
<p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" 
onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.more {
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; }
a.showLink, a.hideLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #36f;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background: transparent url('down.gif') no-repeat left; }
a.hideLink {
    background: transparent url('up.gif') no-repeat left; }
a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; }
```

JavaScript:

```
function showHide(shID) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

I will admit that I don't personally follow everything going on here but I think somehow these examples and the two different links can give you the outcome you are after.

Comment: Thanks for this - I have the first part detecting the mobile browser - I will try it out and let you know.